# How to create a directory with a UNC path in a powershell script with ansible?

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible

I'm trying to create a directory on a network drive using ansible (version 2.9). I made a powershell script which I've copied to the server and I'm calling via `win_command`.

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path \\\\server\path\a\b
```

When I run the script on a Windows server, it correctly creates the directory at `\\server\path\a\b`, however, when I run it via ansible, it creates a directory at `C:\server\path\a\b`.

```
- name: Run create dir script
  win_command: 'powershell C:\Temp\script.ps1'
  become: yes
  vars:
    ansible_become_user: "network_user"
    ansible_become_pass: "network_password"
    ansible_become_method: runas
    ansible_become_flags: logon_type=new_credentials logon_flags=netcredentials_only
```

How do I get it to not create the directory in the `C:\` drive?